# Convert Vue Component to HTML in advance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to create a vuejs component and pass it into a library (mapbox) as pure html. Mapbox has a setHtml method for popups that I'm trying to populate.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup/

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: false })
.setLngLat([-96, 37.8])
.setHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>')
.addTo(map);
```

I haven't been able to find any way to pre-render a specific component into html that I could then insert into the mapbox call. Sort of like v-html in reverse.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with pre render? Die you try to build it? Then register it and just use it? E.g. https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set ref attribute for your component, and then you can get rendered HTML content of component by using `this.$refs.ComponentRef.$el.outerHTML`, and remember don't do this when created.

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <Hello ref="hello" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './Hello.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Hello,
  },
  created() {
    // wrong, $el is not exists then
    // console.log(this.$refs.hello.$el.outerHTML)
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.hello.$el.outerHTML)
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! 

You pointed me in the right direction. I wound up doing a Vue.extend to create the element since it was going to be created repeatedly with different props.


`        const HelloCtor = Vue.extend(Hello);
        const vm = new HelloCtor({
          propsData: {
            featuredImage,
            summary,
            title,
            url,
          }
        }).$mount('#mount');`

followed by the outerHTML

Still running into a few NUXT related issues but the Vue element is mounting correctly